# Singleton bean inside session bean in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, singleton

Using Spring I have a Session bean that contains a Singleton bean and when the session is saved (Using a Redis database) the servlet crashes because it tries to serialize the Singleton bean. What can I do to avoid that?

Note: I can do that making Singleton bean as a transient inside the Session bean. But, it is not exists an Spring way to do something like that ?

Comment: is your Singleton  bean not serializable?what is the problem in making it transient?

Comment: It is not serializable because it is not session data. I just expect that Spring only persist on the Redis database the session data automatically looking the annotations and not have to implement the Serializable interface and mark the data that is Singleton-scoped like transient.